# vba: open workbook and change sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a sheet and after this, open the copy to change the first sheet's name.

This is the code inserted on `Module1`:

```
Sub CopiarNovaPlanilha()
Dim wkb As Workbook

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "I:\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\10 - Alocação das equipes\Consulta Alocados\ALOCACAO TECNICOS.xlsx"

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("I:\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\10 - Alocação das equipes\Consulta Alocados\ALOCACAO TECNICOS.xlsx")
wkb.Sheets(1).Name = "FUNCIONARIOS"

End Sub
```

The first part of the `Sub` to save a copy works perfectly. Although when I try to run the second part it gives me the following error:

> Run-time error 1004: Excel cannot open the file

And it says that it can't understand the extension `.xlsx` or that maybe the file is corrupted, but I've checked and the file is ok.

Does anyone knows which problem is that?

Comment: Do you want a copy of the workbook or a single worksheet in a new workbook?

Comment: @Jeeped I want to copy the workbook and then change the name of the first sheet of my copied workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
Private Sub derp()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\dcoats\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path)
    wbk.Sheets(1).Name = "FUNCIONARIOS"
End Sub
```

So maybe check your string thats the path to your workbook?

EDIT

I just tried this and it works as well.

```
Private Sub derp()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\dcoats\Desktop\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\10 - Alocação das equipes\Consulta Alocados\Book1.xlsx"
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path)
    wbk.Sheets(1).Name = "FUNCIONARIOS"
End Sub
```

And I just tried this as well

```
Private Sub derp()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\dcoats\Desktop\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\10 - Alocação das equipes\Consulta Alocados\yaybook.xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs path, FileFormat:=52
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path)
    wbk.Sheets(1).Name = "FUNCIONARIOS"
End Sub
```

Everything works, so we might be missing details

Comment: Since the path is the same as the `SaveCopyAs` (and it was saved in the correct place), I guess my path is correct... But I tested this and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @paulinhax What Doug suggest here is to save your workbook to a simple path - The characters in your path such as "Supervisão\10 - Alocação d" might cause an issue while Excel trying to access

Comment: I cant see what the issue might be though? It work flawlessly for me, and this is pretty straight forward. Are there other details you havent added?

Comment: @Alex I didnt think about the special characters being an issue. Good catch

Comment: @Alex thanks, I thought about that although I can't change these characters. But it shouldn't cause an issue in the first line too? Because it's working and copying correctly.

Comment: @paulinhax Can you store the path in a string variable and use it like i did above? Or did you try that already?

Comment: @paulinhax I just tried by recreatign your path name and no issue whatsoever

Comment: @DougCoats Yeah, I mean you code seems truly reasonable for me so I really don't know what is the problem that I got here for not working.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't want to Hijack Doug's answer, so here's a way to test:
>
> Try comment out the second part of your code - leave the "saveas" and
>   run. After finish go check your file in the destination path - see if
>   you can open it successfully by manual.
>
> Now in a NEW sub open up this file by code. Do NOT set the sheet name yet. Let
>   us know the result

Edit:

Try saving the worksheet to a new workbook and save the new workbook:

```
Sub test()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim path As String

path = "C:\Users\dcoats\Desktop\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\10 - Alocação das equipes\Consulta Alocados\"

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set nwb = Workbooks.Add

wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy before:=nwb.Sheets(1)

nwb.SaveAs path & "test2.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Update "Sheet1" to whatever worksheetname you're saving

Comment: You had a good point here. The file is created but it doesn't open even that it appears on the destination file as a workbook.

Comment: @paulinhax that means the saveas part isn't working for you - check your folder access privilege, or simply save it to somewhere you do have read / write access

Comment: I tried something like this. I changed the destination to my private folders and still have the same problem. So I changed the `.xlsx` to `.xlsm` just for checking and now the file is opening correctly... I don't know what was this issue.

Comment: @paulinhax ha we all missed an important point here - yes file with macro needs to be save as .xlsm.  Unless it's a different file that you're saving

Comment: I see your point but the main objective here was just copying the sheet without the macros. So I guess I used `SaveCopyAs` instead of `SaveAs`... But I didn't want to use `FileFormat:=51` because I don't want to open the file after, you understand?